# How can Viewers Control Date Range Comparison in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to have an option for a user (not developer) to choose specific Date range comparison period?

For example, for total `Sessions` (1 January - 15 January), is it possible to choose another date by user? I know that it is possible to do for developer of report but I want that user of the report to choose the date of comparison.

Like this in Google Analytics:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I think i got your point. Comparison range for user will always be previous period of selected date range.
For example if user selects data of 23-Feb to 29-Feb then, comparison will be with  16-Feb to 22-Feb and user can not change that. User can change a data and comparison will be changed accordingly.

I hope my answer help you to understand it is not possible as of now.